# c GTK3 Text should scoll upward and not hide

Tags: c, gtk3

here is my problem: I just put a gtk_text_view_new() in a gtk_scrolled_window_new(). Now when I write in the textField, at the end of the gtk_widget_set_size_request->high the text is hidden and the whole text does not scroll upwards as I want.
-> The textfield should automatically scroll upwards and show its last line.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *myGrid;
    GtkWidget *scollwindow;
    GtkWidget *textField;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkWidget *quitbutton;

//---------------------widgets-------------------------------
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    quitbutton = gtk_button_new_with_label("QUIT");
    myGrid = gtk_grid_new ();

//---------------------textField-------------------------------
    textField = gtk_text_view_new ();
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (textField));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "Hello, this is some text, ", -1);

//---------------------insert textField in scrollwindow-------------------------------

    scollwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL,NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scollwindow), textField);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scollwindow), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);

//---------------------widgets size-------------------------------
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (scollwindow, 200, 200);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 200, 200);

//---------------------grid attache-------------------------------
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), scollwindow,    0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(myGrid), quitbutton,    0, 1, 1, 1);

//---------------------add to grid-------------------------------
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), myGrid);

//---------------------signals-------------------------------
    g_signal_connect(quitbutton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just change line " gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scollwindow), textField);" to "gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(scollwindow), textField);"